How do I designate the 2nd subscription name for Application Insights CLI Create command
My command:
az monitor app-insights component create --app $appin --subscription $sub --resource-group $rg-for-insights-component --workspace workspace-in-different-Subscription --location centralus

error:
Could not retrieve the Log Analytics workspace from ARM: /subscriptions/GUID/resourceGroups/rg-for-insights-component/providers/microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/workspace-in-different-Subscription
Of course that workspace exists in a different subscription, how would it find?  How do I provide the 2nd subscription name using the CLI?
The GUI version allows for a seperate name

edit:  When I view the parameters JSON in the GUI Azure Portal, is see
"workspaceResourceId": {
            "value": "/subscriptions/**GUID**/resourcegroups/ResourceGroupOfWorkspace/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/LAWorkspaceName" }

can this UNCish workspace name be entered into the CLI command somehow?

Have you tried moving a workspace resource from one subscription to another one? @josh

No, but I've successfully created an Insights where the workspace was already in the same resource group.  Of course it worked fine.  The Microsoft Docs seem to assume this most basic scenario.   But they state the LA workspace CAN be in a different subscription.

Ok let me check and update you. @josh

Updated. Please check. @josh

You can use the flag --workspace and pass your workspace resource id to the command
There is also documentation from Microsoft regarding the command


How do I designate the 2nd subscription name for Application Insights CLI Create command:

You cannot directly pass the workspace existed in another subscription with az monitor app-insights component create commands --workspace argument.
In order to achieve that, you first set the workspace subscription and retrieve the workspace ID or name as shown below.
az account set --subscription "Workspacesubscription"
name=$(az monitor log-analytics workspace show --name "newws" --resource-group "Jahnavi" --subscription "Workspacesubscription" --query name --output tsv)


Once you are done with the above, clear the subscriptions and CLI cache using az account clear command and authenticate to azure account with your corresponding credentials. Now set the current subscription in which you want to create an insights component using az account set.
az account clear
az login
az account set --subscription "1stSubscription"

Note: Make sure that the logged in user has a necessary permission (Eg: Contributor role) to access and retrieve the resource from the other subscription.
I have created an insights component with the below command format by passing the workspace name as shown.
az monitor app-insights component create --app "appin" --resource-group "Jahnavi" --workspace $name --location centralus --kind 
web --application-type web  --subscription "1stsubscription"



